# django-haystack и elasticsearch исключить из результатов совпадение предлогов (stop words)

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, полнотекстовый-поиск, haystack

Никак не получается правильно настроить связку django/haystack/elasticsearch. Всё индексируется замечательно. Но, если поисковый запрос содержит союз или предлог русского языка, то появляются много ненужных результатов, в которых есть только эта буква. Перепробовал кучу вариантов настройки. Привожу наиболее правильный на мой взгляд. После каждого изменения конфигурации вручную удалял индекс (curl -X DELETE http://localhost:9200/haystack_ru) и вновь индексировал (django-admin rebuild_index)

django == 1.6.5 (переход на более свежие пока невозможен)

django-haystack == 2.4.1

elasticsearch

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/                                                                                                   

{
"name" : "Hank Pym",
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"cluster_uuid" : "oQGMZh6QSlulXIJSasYEEg",
"version" : {
  "number" : "2.4.6",
  "build_hash" : "5376dca9f70f3abef96a77f4bb22720ace8240fd",
  "build_timestamp" : "2017-07-18T12:17:44Z",
  "build_snapshot" : false,
  "lucene_version" : "5.5.4"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': '__main.search_backends.RussianElasticSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack_ru',
},
}
```

__main.search_backends.RussianElasticSearchEngine

```
from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import 
ElasticsearchSearchBackend, ElasticsearchSearchEngine
from haystack.backends import elasticsearch_backend


# Hack analyser
elasticsearch_backend.DEFAULT_FIELD_MAPPING = {'type': 'string', 
'analyzer': 'russian_and_english'}


class RussianElasticSearchBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
    'settings': {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["haystack_ngram", "lowercase"]
                },
                "edgengram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["haystack_edgengram", "lowercase"]
                },
                'russian_and_english': {
                    'type': 'custom',
                    'tokenizer': 'standard',
                    "filter": ['lowercase', 'russian_morphology', 'english_morphology', 'ru_stopwords'],
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "haystack_ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 15,
                },
                "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 15,
                    "side": "front"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "haystack_ngram": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 15
                },
                "haystack_edgengram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 15
                },
                'ru_stopwords': {
                    'type': 'stop',
                    "stopwords": '_russian_',
                },
                'ru_stemming': {
                    'type': 'snowball',
                    'language': 'Russian',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class RussianElasticSearchEngine(ElasticsearchSearchEngine):
   backend = RussianElasticSearchBackend
```

Answer (score 1):

После долгих поисков и изучения, удалось настроить полнотекстовый поиск для **django 1.6.5** с помощью **elasticsearch** через прослойку в виде пакета **django-haystack**. Большая часть справедлива и для более новых версий **django** (примерно так же настроил поиск на **django 1.10**).
Если кратко,то по пунктам:

1. тег `{% highlight %}` никак не связан с поисковым  движком и просто подсвечивает любую подстроку в любой строке.
2. для включения русской морфологии в **elasticsearch** нужно установить плагин. Вот здесь сами плагины под различные версии и инструкции как установить https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology.
3. для того, чтобы **elasticsearch** учитывал морфологию, нужно соответственно настроить индекс. Для этого нужно написать свой **SearchBackend** для **django-haystack** на основе стандартного. Ниже мой рабочий пример:

   ```
   import haystack
   from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import ElasticsearchSearchBackend, ElasticsearchSearchEngine

   from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import elasticsearch
   from haystack.backends import elasticsearch_backend
   from elasticsearch.exceptions import NotFoundError


   # Hack analyser
   elasticsearch.DEFAULT_FIELD_MAPPING = {'type': 'string', 'analyzer': 'custom_russian_and_english'}
   elasticsearch_backend.DEFAULT_FIELD_MAPPING = {'type': 'string', 'analyzer': 'custom_russian_and_english'}


   class CustomElasticSearchBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):
       DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
           "settings": {
               "analysis": {
                   "analyzer": {
                       "custom_russian_and_english": {
                           "type": "custom",
                           "tokenizer": "standard",
                           "filter": ["lowercase", "russian_morphology", "english_morphology",
                                      "my_stopwords"]
                       }
                   },
                   "filter": {
                       "my_stopwords": {
                           "type": "stop",
                           "stopwords": "а,без,более,бы,был,была,были,было,быть,в,вам,вас,весь,во,вот,все,всего,всех,вы,где,да,даже,для,до,его,ее,если,есть,еще,же,за,здесь,и,из,или,им,их,к,как,ко,когда,кто,ли,либо,мне,может,мы,на,надо,наш,не,него,нее,нет,ни,них,но,ну,о,об,однако,он,она,они,оно,от,очень,по,под,при,с,со,так,также,такой,там,те,тем,то,того,тоже,той,только,том,ты,у,уже,хотя,чего,чей,чем,что,чтобы,чье,чья,эта,эти,это,я,a,an,and,are,as,at,be,but,by,for,if,in,into,is,it,no,not,of,on,or,such,that,the,their,then,there,these,they,this,to,was,will,with"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       def setup(self):
           """
           Defers loading until needed.
           """
           # Get the existing mapping & cache it. We'll compare it
           # during the ``update`` & if it doesn't match, we'll put the new
           # mapping.
           try:
               self.existing_mapping = self.conn.indices.get_mapping(index=self.index_name)
           except NotFoundError:
               pass
           except Exception:
               if not self.silently_fail:
                   raise

           unified_index = haystack.connections[self.connection_alias].get_unified_index()
           self.content_field_name, field_mapping = self.build_schema(unified_index.all_searchfields())
           current_mapping = {
               'modelresult': {
                   'properties': field_mapping,
                   # this option doesnt work with elasticsearch 2.4.6
                   # '_boost': {
                   #     'name': 'boost',
                   #     'null_value': 1.0
                   # }
               }
           }

           if current_mapping != self.existing_mapping:
               try:
                   # Make sure the index is there first.
                   self.conn.indices.create(index=self.index_name, body=self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS, ignore=400)
                   self.conn.indices.put_mapping(index=self.index_name, doc_type='modelresult', body=current_mapping)
                   self.existing_mapping = current_mapping
               except Exception:
                   if not self.silently_fail:
                       raise

           self.setup_complete = True


   class CustomElasticSearchEngine(ElasticsearchSearchEngine):
       backend = CustomElasticSearchBackend
   ```

в коде есть также хак метода **setup**. В нём закомментены неактуальные настройки **elasticsearch**

```
             # '_boost': {
                    #     'name': 'boost',
                    #     'null_value': 1.0
                    # }
```

меняем соответственно настройки

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'search.haystack_backend.CustomElasticSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

после этого нужно сделать реиндекс `(django-admin rebuild_index)/`

4. Если нужна подсветка результатов, необходимо использовать `haystack.forms.HighlightSearchForm` (ну или самому переопределить метод `search` добавив к запросу `highlight()` )
5. Теперь при отображении результатов поиска можно использовать список с отрывками текста, в которых искомые строки выделены **elasticsearch** спец тегом (по-умолчанию em)

> ```
> {% for excerpt in result.highlighted %}
>    <div class="search-result__excerpt">{{ excerpt|safe }}</div>
> {% endfor %}
> ```

и ещё одно замечание. **Haystack** не выдаст никакой ошибки, если при создании индекса ваши настройки по какой-либо причине не были учтены. В этом случае просто будут использоваться настройки по умолчанию. Поэтому, если что-то не получается, в первую очередь проверьте какой анализатор у вас настроен для `"text"` . Для этого можно прямо с браузера зайти по адресу http://localhost:9200/haystack?pretty . Должно быть примерно так:

```
  "text" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "analyzer" : "custom_russian_and_english"
  }
```